# Updating website with gitolite. Where is repo located on server?

Tags: wordpress, git, file-upload, version-control, file-transfer

My Wordpress files are currently in a gitolite repo on my server. I want to take it live by symlinking the repo to /var/www. This way I could keep editing and push updates. But I don't know where to find the actual files.

I'd expect them to be in ~git/repositories/project.git, but looking around, I don't see them. Is there a way to do what I'm thinking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Git, there are two different kinds of repositories: repositories that consist of a working copy and a folder called `.git` inside that contains Git's files, and *bare repositories* that don't have a working copy and are just the bare `.git` folder.  You can only push to bare repositories, so server software such as gitolite is using these.  You can tell by looking at a repository's name: by convention, the name of bare repositoriy ends with `.git`.

> I want to take it live by symlinking the repo to /var/www. This way I could keep editing and push updates. But I don't know where to find the actual files.

The reason is they aren't there.  There are several ways to achieve what you are trying to do; probably the most easy way is to use a [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on your server-side repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't think to just clone the repo on the server to /www.